# Debian 10 Buster not recognizing domain name assigned by dhcp

Tags: debian, debian-buster

I have two buster servers that get assigned static IPs via DHCP (dhclient). the DHCP server assigns all parameters including domain (mydomain.org). One server works fine, i.e. `hostname -f`. On this server `/etc/resolv.conf` is correct:

```
 # Generated by NetworkManager
    search mydomain.org
    nameserver x.x.x.x
```

`hostname -f` on the working server returns the FQDN as it should.

But the other server doesn't get the domain properly. `hostname -f` simply returns the hostname and `/etc/resolv.conf` isn't populated as per the DHCP settings:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search lan
nameserver x.x.x.x
```

If I manually run `sudo dhclient -4 -v` /etc/resolv.conf gets updated properly with `search mydomain.org`. However, after a restart or `systemctl restart NetworkManager` `/etc/resolv.conf` returns to the incorrect state.

What am I missing here? How do I get networkmanager to properly assign the search domain in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out NetworkManager looks at config files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Looking at the file `Wired Connection 1` in that folder, I found some static assignments under the [ipv4] heading, specifically the problem was with this line:

```
[ipv4]
dns-search=lan
```

removing that line and restarting NetworkManager with `systemctl restart NetworkManager` fixed the problem.